# Fastest way to compare scanned Beacon's UUID with my database

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, beacon

I am experimenting with an Android Beacon Listening App. To simplify my question lets assume that I just want to have a local database with a list of Beacons and be able to identify which Beacons of these are currently being scanned.

I have several ideas regarding possible approaches, however, I would like your advice on how could I do that as fast as possible.

Please also consider the following:

1) Part of the UUID (6 last Bytes) is common to all Beacons (so maybe I should avoid comparing that part)

2) I do not mind if your recommendation demands having stored my Beacons in a specific way (to fasten the comparisons).

PS. I was thinking of getting a byte array of the first 10 bytes and trying to convert them into a long and search for that as a key within my Beacon's HashMap. Dunno

Thx for your time!

Comment: The less you do, the better. UUIDs aren't enormous. Just let the SQL do the comparing.

Comment: To simplify your question, it is not really beacon-specific.   You are essentially asking how to best optimize a comparison of one 10 byte (the first 10 bytes of the beacon  UUID)  sequence against a pre-defined list of 10 byte sequences.  You may get more and better answers on this forum if you ask your question this way, and tag the question correspondingly.  (That said, I doubt this optimization is even necessary unless your list of UUIDs is very large, i.e. over 100.)

Comment: Good point. Yes we are talking about 4000 UUIDs